# Ruby Rest Response Handling

Tags: ruby, rest

iam new to programming as well as ruby. I have written a class for some implementation tasks via REST API. Now iam trying to write a response function to check if the implementation tasks were successful, however, at my current knowledge level, I find it hard to find a way to do so.

here is a sample of an implementation task:

```
def add_v4object(organization,v4object)

  @resource["/api/v1/#{organization}/v4address"].post(v4object, content_type: 'json')
```

For the response handling I have been thinking about something like this

```
  def implementation_successful(response_code)

  if reponse_code == 200 || response_code == 201
  return true
  else
    log response
    return false
  end

response = my_class.add__v4object(organization, v4object)
my_class.implementation_successful(response.code)
```

However iam having some issues with this, since the REST class handles successful calls different than exceptions:
- succesful-> i can catch the response in a variable and can use the "response.code" method
- exceptions: I need to handle those with a "rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse", but this would mean, that i need to add a rescue to each and every of my functions which do a REST call..

At this point i get kinda lost. What is a feasible way to check whether or not my rest call was successful ?

Comment: The straightforward approach is to do begin -> rescue every api call. The API will probably return appropriate error code in case something went wrong, but the client will raise. You could "rescue => e" which will catch every exception raised by the RestClient and it depend what do you want to do with that later. Log it, retry the call or may be re raise to bobble it up.

Comment: one of my colleague came up with the idea to use switch statements. This will summarize all methods in one block, so i dont have to repeat the rescue  statement every time, however i dont like this a lot.

Comment: So much for separation of concerns.. If you don't like it you should him.